# Comparing URL strings in PHP

Tags: php, string, comparison

I'm trying to use the query from a GET url to determine the content of a page.
This is what I have (sentences edited for clarity):

```
    <?php 
//decalre variables
$title ='';
$welcome = '';
$params = '';

$params = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
echo $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
echo $params;

if ($params='') {
    header('start.html') ;
} else {
    if ($params === "selection=republic") {
        //echo $params;
        //echo 'Republic';
        $title = "Private";
        $welcome = "Our .";
        $signoff = "The Republic will strike back!";
    } 
    else if ($params === "selection=rebels")    {
        //echo $params;
        //echo 'Rebels';
        $title = "Comrade";
        $welcome = "Hey comrade, welcome to the Underground Network!";
        $declaration="You see,o's!";
        $signoff = "Rebel!!";
    } 
    else if ($params === "selection=robots"){
        //echo $params;
        //echo 'Robots';
        $title = "Bit";
        $welcome = "Our data ";
        $declaration="Knowledge w.";
        $signoff = "ed now.";
    }
    else {
        echo 'There was an error - please go back.';
    }
}
```

The first echo shows the correct URL, but the comparison gets stuck at the third option. 
Help!

Comment: I believe the first `if ($params='')` should be `==`.

Comment: Why not use `$_GET['selection']`?

Comment: also it's much better to use if(empty($variable)) instead of if($variable == '') ... empty detects if there's no value or whitespaces, (and 0's too so be careful with ints)

Comment: Thanks all - the "==" fixed it and using is simpler

Answer (score 1):

There are way better ways of parsing the query string than `$SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`, specifically you can use `$_GET` to access a specific parameter.  Example: www.example.com?name=Dave&age=30...
to get the name, you can do `$_GET['name']` and it will return `Dave`.  I think a better way to do this would be something like:

```
$selection = $_GET['selection'];
if (empty($selection)) {
    header('start.html') ;
}

else {
     $vars = array(
          'republic'=>array('title'=>'Private', 'welcome'=> 'Our .', 'declaration'=>'', 'signoff' => 'The Replublic will strike back'),
          'rebels'=>array('title'=>'Comrade', 'welcome' => "Hey comrade, welcome to the Underground Network!", 'declaration'=>"You see,o's!",'signoff' => "Rebel!!"),
          'robots'=>array('title'=>'Bit', 'welcome'=>'Our data', 'declaration'=>'Knowlegge W', 'signoff'=>'Ed now')
      );

      list($title, $welcome, $declaration, $signoff) = $vars[$selection];
}
```

Comment: and `$SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`?

Answer (score 1):

This comes from the triple  `=`  sign, that compares the value and the type. You should see [the difference here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80646/how-do-the-equality-double-equals-and-identity-triple-equals-comparis).

I suggest you only use two equals and by the way, you could ease your code by using the $_GET['selection'] variable instead:

```
<?php 
//decalre variables
$title ='';
$welcome = '';
$params = '';

$params = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
echo $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
echo $params;

if (!isset($_GET['selection']) { // Check whether selection is set 
    header('start.html') ;
} else {
    if ($_GET['selection'] == "republic") {
        //echo $params;
        //echo 'Republic';
        $title = "Private";
        $welcome = "Our .";
        $signoff = "The Republic will strike back!";
    } 
    else if ($_GET['selection'] == "rebels")    {
        //echo $params;
        //echo 'Rebels';
        $title = "Comrade";
        $welcome = "Hey comrade, welcome to the Underground Network!";
        $declaration="You see,o's!";
        $signoff = "Rebel!!";
    } 
    else if ($_GET['selection'] == "robots"){
        //echo $params;
        //echo 'Robots';
        $title = "Bit";
        $welcome = "Our data ";
        $declaration="Knowledge w.";
        $signoff = "ed now.";
    }
    else {
        echo 'There was an error - please go back.';
    }
}
```